# IE7 Ignoring all CSS except Backgrond image

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Not even sure where to start with this one, but im hoping someone else has had this issue.

When using IE7 (not IE7 mode in IE9), all the styles seems to be dropped except for the background and all the text is shrunk to around 2px. So its just a page with all the images, text and inputs barfed into the page.

Here is an image:

[image]

Any Ideas as to what would cause this?

Comment: Can you link to the site? Is there any JavaScript whatsoever being used? Are you using any HTML5 semantic elements? Does the [HTML validate](http://validator.w3.org/)? Does the [CSS validate](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)?

Comment: A bigger image would be helpful ;)

Comment: Thats 1:1 size how it shows up! There are no HTML5 Elements being used.HTML validates, checking CSS now.

Answer (score 1):

figured it out: for some reason I had zoom:1px; in my css reset.

Fixed!